# Serverless python custom packaging with serverless-python-requirements

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework + serverless-python-requirements plugin to package my application.

I have this following project structure

```
src/
    requirements.txt
    function_a.py
    function_b.py
    common/
        common_1.py
        common_2.py
```

With this function configuration the zip artifacts contains the common and function_* lambda source files plus dependencies, which is what I want.

Serverless configuration - 1

```
 functionA:
    module: src
    handler: function_a.handler
    package:
      include:
        - src/common/**
        - src/function_a.py

  functionB:
    module: src
    handler: function_b.handler
    package:
      include:
        - src/common/**
        - src/function_b.py
```

Now I would like to move the function_b to a nested src folder src/function_b and have its own requirements.txt file

```
src/
    requirements.txt
    function_a.py
    function_b/
        function_b.py
        requirements.txt
    common/
        common_1.py
        common_2.py
```

but when I try to pack it using this serverless configuration the function_b zip file doesn't contain the /common/** sources but only the function_b and its dependencies.

Serverless configuration - 2

```
  functionB:
    module: src/function_b
    handler: function_b.handler
    package:
      include:
        - src/common/**
        - src/function_b/function_b.py
```

The other relevant part of the serverless.yml file is this

```
pythonRequirements:
    slim: true
    useStaticCache: true
    useDownloadCache: true
    cacheLocation: './._cache'
    staticCacheMaxVersions: 10
    dockerizePip: non-linux

package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./**
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or is this some plugin/serverless limitation/bug ?

Comment: I've tried with the same folder structure and getting the same issue. Without the plugin include, exclude works fine. I think it's a limitation with the plugin. Have you had any luck after that?

Comment: @DurjaArai no, but there is a workaround  using 'vendor' on the github issue I opened here https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/435#issuecomment-575914543

Comment: Do you have a sample project that works with the Vendor option as it's not working in my project. I tried to create a new one with sample files and still not able to get the files in my package. Want to make sure I am doing right.

Comment: No Sorry i dont you can try asking in the thread of the open issue